# Load Balance in Nodejs through nginx using redis as a session storage

Tags: node.js, session, nginx, redis, load-balancing

I tried to Load Balance in Nodejs through nginx using redis as a session storage.

I am using 3 Machine

1. Machine A (192.168.14.65) - Nginx, Redis is install
2. Machine B (192.168.14.92) - nodejs is installed
3. Machine C (192.168.9.9) - nodejs is installed

I set a session variable in Machine B and I am trying to access same session variable through Machine C.

I am using redis as a session storage, so I should access the variable in Machine B.

The coding of Machine B is(file name as app.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var redis   = require("redis");
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var client  = redis.createClient();
var app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ssshhhhh',
    // create new redis store.
    store: new redisStore({ host: '192.168.14.65', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.session);
  req.session.helloworld = 'helloworld';
  res.send('set session');

});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("App Started on PORT 3000");
});
```

coding for Machine C is(file name as app.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var redis   = require("redis");
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var client  = redis.createClient();
var app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ssshhhhh',
    // create new redis store.
    store: new redisStore({ host: '192.168.14.65', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if(req.session.helloworld) {
    res.send('get session: '+ req.session.helloworld);
  } else {
    res.send('no session: ');
  } 

});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("App Started on PORT 3000");
});
```

and i have package.json in both machine

package.json code

```
{
  "name": "Node-Session-Redis",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.2.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.0",
    "connect-redis": "^2.3.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.5",
    "ejs": "^2.3.1",
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "mysql": "^2.7.0",
    "redis": "^0.12.1"
  }
}
```

I run the code using command

```
node app.js
```

Everything is working fine in Machine B.

but I am getting some error in Machine C.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'helloworld' of undefined
    at /home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/app.js:19:17
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at session (/home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/node_modules/express-session/index.js:159:61)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/local/PAYODA/balachandran.v/js/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

When I tried req.session in console I got 
Error in Machine B
Machine B Error.

```
{ cookie:     { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

Machine C Error

```
undefine
```

Can anybody please tell me where i am wrong?
Thanks in advance